# How to prevent changing picturebox's size when changing size of the control that contains the picturebox?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a user control with picturebox on it. I want the picturebox size to remain the same, but the form that contains the user control changes the hight of the control and the picturebox's height changes. Can I somehow keep the height (and width) constant?

Answer (score 2):

If the picture box is docked or has anchors set, it "follows" the parent's height (and width, if the correct anchor/docking is configured).

Please check whether you set the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties correctly. [See also this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165908.html).